# Write a portable (root-finder) solver class for different (curve-making) classes

Tags: oop, fortran, portable-class-library, fortran2003

I am very keen to implement object-oriented programming (OOP) capabilities of FORTRAN 2003 (F2003). My question is more about the design of the program. Let's say I have a *solver*, like root finder of a function ***f(x)=0***; in its simplest format in FORTRAN it would get the shape of

```
function solver(f,a,b) result(root)
    [some definition of variables]
    [some iterative procedures]
    root = ...
end function
```

In the previous versions of FORTRAN like f95, to get the portability, the code is compiled separately and an external function is passed to the *solver*. 
Now from F2003 OOP viewpoint, lets say in general case we have a class for the *solver*

```
type solver_t
   real :: a,b,root
contains
   procedure :: solve => solve_solver_t          ! root=this%solve()
   [some initialization and post-calculation procedures]
end type
```

and another class for our curve

```
type curve_t
    [some variable definition]
contains
    [some initialization procedures]
    procedure :: func => function_curve_t    ! y=this%func(x)
    procedure :: plot => plot_curve
end type
```

and there would be more different curve classes (types). Now, how can I connect these 2 concepts in a way I compile my solver class (without knowing the curve class/type), and  I'll be able to implement it without a change whenever I write a new different curve class (like 2nd_order_polynomial_curve, 3rd_order_polynomial_curve, log_curve, exp_curve,...). I mean, at the end, somehow I get the roots of the curve.

Comment: The book *Modern Fortran in Practice* (Markus) has examples of this.

Comment: I am going to read the book, thanks @Casey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one example of how to use F2003 OOP to implement this idea.  I'll start with a module to be built into a shared library:

```
module solver
  implicit none

  type, abstract :: curve_t
   contains
     procedure(func_f), pass(this), deferred :: f
  end type curve_t

  type :: solver_t
     class(curve_t), pointer :: curve
   contains
     procedure, pass :: solve => solve_root_bisect_method
  end type solver_t

  abstract interface
     function func_f(this, x)
       import curve_t
       class(curve_t) :: this
       real, intent(in) :: x
       real :: func_f
     end function func_f
  end interface

contains

  function solve_root_bisect_method(this, a_start, b_start) result(root)
    implicit none
    class(solver_t) :: this
    real, intent(in) :: a_start, b_start
    real :: root, c, eps, a, b
    integer :: i, imax
    imax = 100
    eps = 1e-5
    a = a_start
    b = b_start

    do i=1, imax
       c = (a+b)/2.
       if ( (this%curve%f(c) == 0) .or. ((b-a)/2. < eps)) then
          root = c
          return
       end if
       if (sign(1.,this%curve%f(c)) == sign(1.,this%curve%f(a))) then
          a = c
       else
          b = c
       end if
    end do
    ! solution did not converge, produce error
    root = -999
  end function solve_root_bisect_method
end module solver
```

This defines an abstract class to represent curves and a class for the solver.  The solver could also be made abstract, but for the purposes of the demo I chose not to do that and provide one solver.  You could still extend this type and provide a different procedure for the solve interface.  You can compile this into a shared library, e.g.

```
gfortran -shared -fPIC -o solver.so solver.f90
```

which will yield `solver.so` and `solver.mod`.  I did this extra step to demonstrate portability and compiling without knowledge of any curves.

Now we can pretend to be a third party who wants to use this handy library to find roots of arbitrary curves.  First we can define our own module to extend curve and provide some functions.

```
module curves
  use solver
  implicit none

  type, extends(curve_t) :: linear_curve
     real :: m, b
   contains
     procedure, pass(this) :: f => f_linear
  end type linear_curve

  type, extends(curve_t) :: polynomial_curve
     real :: a, b, c
   contains
     procedure, pass(this) :: f => f_polynomial
  end type polynomial_curve

contains

  real function f_linear(this, x)
    use solver
    implicit none
    class(linear_curve) :: this
    real, intent(in) :: x
    f_linear = this%m * x + this%b
  end function f_linear

  real function f_polynomial(this, x)
    use solver
    implicit none
    class(polynomial_curve) :: this
    real, intent(in) :: x
    f_polynomial = this%a*x*x + this%b*x + this%c
  end function f_polynomial
end module curves
```

This defines types for a linear curve and a polynomial curve which contain their parameters and a function for computing `y` as a function of `x` given those parameters. Because we derive from `curve_t` and conform to the interface for `f`, we can use these classes easily with the `solver_t` class.

Here is a small program to demonstrate this

```
program test
  use solver
  use curves
  implicit none

  type(linear_curve), target :: linear
  type(polynomial_curve), target :: parabola
  type(solver_t) :: root_solver
  real :: root

  linear%m = 1.
  linear%b = 0.     ! y=x
  parabola%a = 1.
  parabola%b = 0.
  parabola%c = -1.  ! y=x^2-1

  root_solver%curve => linear
  root = root_solver%solve(-1., 1.)
  print *, "root  = ", root

  root_solver%curve => parabola
  root = root_solver%solve(-4., 0.5)
  print *, "root1 = ", root
  root = root_solver%solve(-0.5, 4.)
  print *, "root2 = ", root
end program test
```

Here I declare some curves, set their parameters and then call the solver to find a root.  If you compile our curve module, the test program and link to the shared library we created earlier, we can run with the output:

```
% ./roots                               
 root  =    0.00000000    
 root1 =   -1.00000286    
 root2 =    1.00000286
```

(the quality of the roots is limited by the quality of the example solver I dumped into the first module, you can do better).   This isn't the best demo of pure OO, as the solver_t class could be done better, but I focused on demoing how you would approach multiple user-defined curves without having to know anything about them when solve_t is compiled.